# Why doesn't "else if" work in console.log and keeps popping syntax error?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have a problem with a console. I wanted to make if n<10 else if n<100, and else with console comment. Seems like it won't get me through else if. I tried to find an answer, but nothing worked.

```
let n = 14;
undefined
if (n<10){
  console.log("grats");}
undefined
else if (n<100){console.log("grats2");}
SyntaxError: expected expression, got keyword 'else'
```

Comment: your `else if(n <100) ...` is independent from your `if`. You need to add it to the end of your `if` when you execute/create your `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the browser's console, every line seems to be interpreted and executed separately. When you close your `if`'s curly brace if you stop there, then the expression is executed and on the next line you can't go `else` because the `if` statement is finished.

What you can do is

```
if (condition) {
  // ... operations
} else {
```

by writing else right after closing the curly brace you're telling the console than you're not done yet with the if statement

Comment: I tried to copy the code from a book, "Eloquent Javascript". if, else if, else.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. That bracket behind else if and else saved me. Sadly the book didn't explain it is important.